# Detection of array overflow in C

Tags: arrays, c, buffer

My goal: In C, I'm trying to add to a string character by character, and if I attempt at filling it failed, them expand it by one character.

Question: how can I detect a failure to place data within the bounds of the buffer, and how can it be handled?

Comment: Keep track of the size.

Comment: There's no "failing" to place data within the bounds of an array. If you try to access beyond the end of an array, you're invoking undefined behaviour. It's not possible (in pure C, not depending on any other tools or features) to detect that, you just have to not try in the first place.

Comment: There's no guard rails in C. If you drive off a cliff, that's on you.